# Show "-" if date is empty in dev extreme datagrid

Tags: datagrid, devexpress, devextreme-angular

I'm using dev extreme data grid, I displayed blank if the date is not available.
I want to show "-" if date is empty.

I tried

```
// component.html
[customizeText]="customizeMyText"

// component.ts
 customizeMyText(cellInfo: any) {
    console.log(cellInfo);
    if (cellInfo.value == '' || cellInfo.value == null || cellInfo.value == undefined) {
      return 'NA';
    } else {
      return cellInfo.value;
    }
 }
```

But it gives an error, text.replace is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

The return value on the customizeText function expects a string, change your function to use the valueText instead:

```
customizeMyText(cellInfo) {
if (
  cellInfo.value === "" ||
  cellInfo.value === null ||
  cellInfo.value === undefined
) {
  return "NA";
} else {
  return cellInfo.valueText;
}
```

};

Source: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/#customizeText